# Java swing GUI restructuring - which layouts would work

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am currently working on the user interface for a quiz game. It currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

However, I'm not sure about how to structure the screen accordingly, particularly the following things:

1. Splitting the screen into s several ones (header, where the the timer is... positioned to to the right), ensuring timer is on the right hand side
2. Creating a sidebar for scores
3. Creating a main area for questions
4. Centering all the elements slightly so that there is some padding around it
5. Not losing the elements drawn in `paintComponent`

Which type of layouts would work best from the outset?

My code is as follows (note that the bulk of the work is done in `createWindow` and `paintComponent` is how I draw the responses on screen):

```
final class Gui extends JFrame {
  static String message;
  static String answer;
  private String alertMessage;
  private String guesses;
  private Display display;
  private JTextArea textArea;
  private JButton startButton;
  private JLabel timerLabel;
  private JButton nextButton;
  private int badGuesses;
  private boolean gameOver;
  private Timer timer;
  private ArrayList<JButton> alphabetButtons = new ArrayList<>();

  Gui() {
    createWindow();
  }

  public enum GuiText {
    START("Start"),
    QUIT("Quit"),
    SUBMIT("Submit"),
    RESET("Reset"),
    SEND("Send"),
    NEXT(">"),
    PREVIOUS("<"),
    PAUSE("Pause");

    private String guiText;

    GuiText(String guiText) {
      this.guiText = guiText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return guiText;
    }
  }

  /**
   * This class defines the panel that occupies the large central area in the
   * main panel.  The paintComponent() method in this class is responsible for
   * drawing the content of that panel.  It shows everything that that the user
   * is supposed to see, based on the current values of all the instance variables.
   */
  private class Display extends JPanel {
    Display() {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 250));
      setBackground(new Color(0x00bcda));
      setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
      if (message != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawString(message, 30, 120);
      }
      if (alertMessage != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawString(alertMessage, 30, 150);
      }
      if (gameOver) {
        alertMessage = "Click on \"Next\" to play again.";
      } else {
        g.drawString("Guesses remaining: " + (3 - badGuesses), 770, 40);
      }
      g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      if (answer != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++) {
          if (String.valueOf(answer.charAt(i)).trim().length() > 0) {
            g.drawLine(30 + i * 70, 210, 70 + i * 70, 210);
            if (guesses.indexOf(answer.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
              g.drawString(String.valueOf(answer.charAt(i)), 45 + i * 70, 195);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * The constructor that creates the main panel, which is represented
   * by this class.  It makes all the buttons and subpanels and adds
   * them to the main panel.
   */
  private void createWindow() {
    setJMenuBar(menuBarCreator());

    // The ActionListener that will respond to button clicks.
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();

    // Create the subpanels and add them to the main panel.
    display = new Display();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
    add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Add timer panel
    JPanel timerPanel = new JPanel();
    timerPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    timerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x00bcda));
    add(timerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    // Add timer label
    timerLabel = new JLabel("01:00", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    timerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridy = 0;
    timerLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
    timerPanel.add(timerLabel, c);

    // Add left panel
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    leftPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25, 25, 25, 5));
    leftPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x00bcda));
    add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    // Add previous button
    JButton previousButton = new JButton(String.valueOf(GuiText.PREVIOUS));
    previousButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 60));
    previousButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    leftPanel.add(previousButton, c);

    // Add right panel
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    rightPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25, 25, 25, 25));
    rightPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x00bcda));
    add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    // Add next button
    nextButton = new JButton(String.valueOf(GuiText.NEXT));
    nextButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 60));
    nextButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    rightPanel.add(nextButton, c);

    // Add actual timer
    initialiseTimer();

    // Add bottom panel
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints bottomPanelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    bottomPanelConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    setBackground(new Color(100, 0, 0));

    // Add primary button panel to bottom panel
    JPanel primaryButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    primaryButtonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    primaryButtonPanel.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    bottomPanel.add(primaryButtonPanel, c);

    // Add text area
    textArea = new JTextArea(1, 10);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(0xCCCCCC));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    primaryButtonPanel.add(textArea, c);

    // Add buttons
    JButton sendButton = new JButton(String.valueOf(GuiText.SEND));
    sendButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    sendButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    primaryButtonPanel.add(sendButton);

    // Add secondary button panel
    JPanel secondaryButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    secondaryButtonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    secondaryButtonPanel.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    bottomPanel.add(secondaryButtonPanel, c);

    // Add secondary buttons
    startButton = new JButton(GuiText.START.toString());
    startButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    startButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    secondaryButtonPanel.add(startButton);

    JButton pauseButton = new JButton(GuiText.PAUSE.toString());
    pauseButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    pauseButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    secondaryButtonPanel.add(pauseButton);

    JButton quitButton = new JButton(GuiText.QUIT.toString());
    quitButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    quitButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    secondaryButtonPanel.add(quitButton);

    JButton submitButton = new JButton(GuiText.SUBMIT.toString());
    submitButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    submitButton.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    secondaryButtonPanel.add(submitButton);

    // Add keyboard panel
    JPanel keyboardPanel = new JPanel();
    keyboardPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    keyboardPanel.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    bottomPanel.add(keyboardPanel, c);
    keyboardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 10, 5, 5));
    for (char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
      JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(alphabet));
      button.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
      button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      keyboardPanel.add(button);
      alphabetButtons.add(button);
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"Which type of layout would work best from the outset?"* Often it comes down to which ***layouts*** (plural). Combine layouts for best effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular set of requirements, a `SpringLayout` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is perfect, though it requires a lot of lines of code, and is hard to read. However it it is one of the most flexibility 'out of the box' layout managers.
`SpringLayout` works by applying constraints to elements, bringing them in relative position to each other (including relative to the container). This is flexible, because you are able to achieve almost all configurations where the main focus is the relative position of elements (including some padding and thelike).

Incidentally, you should also be able to achieve what you need with a `GridBagLayout` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), but that might restrict you later on.